# QQ Plot Reference Line not 45°

Tags: matlab, qq-plot

I was plotting (standardized) return data with `qqplot()` in MATLAB against the theoretical quantiles of a normal distribution. However, the line in the QQ-Plot does not have a 45° angle but is rotated a little.

Maybe I misunderstand the concept of a QQ plot but isn't it supposed to be exactly a 45° line?

I put the plot to illustrate the issue.

[image: QQ Plot of standardized return data]

Comment: Standardized return data is well known to be non-normal, so why would it lie on a 45 degree line? Returns are heavier tailed than normal and that's what your data shows as well.

Comment: I'm aware of the non-normality and that the points should not lie on the line itself. I was rather wondering why the line is not 45°.

Comment: Oh sorry, that wasn't clear. I have posted an answer.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Should it be a 45 degree line? It depends!

A QQ plot is the parametric curve defined by:

\begin{align*}
x &= F^{-1}(p)\\
y &= G^{-1}(p)
\end{align*}

for $p \in [0, 1]$. Where $F^{-1}$ and $G^{-1}$ are inverse CDF functions.

If $F = G$ then $x(p)=y(p)$ and it would be on a 45 degree line.

#### Another case...

- Let $\Phi^{-1}(p)$ be the standard normal inverse CDF.
- Let $F^{-1}(p) = \Phi^{-1}(p)$
- Let $G^{-1}(p) = \sigma \Phi^{-1}(p) + \mu$

That is $G$ is the inverse CDF for a normally distributed random variable with mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma$ while $F$ is the inverse CDF for a standard normal variable (i.e. mean 0, standard deviation 1). Then we see:

$$y(p) = \sigma \Phi^{-1}(p) + \mu = \sigma x(p) + \mu$$

That is, the plot is a line $y = \sigma x + \mu$

#### What's going on in your case?

From the [Matlab documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/qqplot.html) for `qqplot`

> Superimposed on the plot is a line joining the first and third
>   quartiles of each distribution (this is a robust linear fit of the
>   order statistics of the two samples). This line is extrapolated out to
>   the ends of the sample to help evaluate the linearity of the data.

So even if you standardized your data, the red line MATLAB plots wouldn't be a 45 degree line if the 1st and 3rd quartiles didn't match the normal distribution.

Comment: Thank you! I thought the red line is constructed so that you can see the deviations from the standard normal quantiles? When I use standardized data, the line should be y=x then, shouldn't it?

Comment: @mscnvrsy The red line I think in MATLAB is constructed to show what it should be if your data followed the normal distribution.

Comment: Is there any way to obtain a 45° line as reference line? I thought this could be achieved by standardizing.

Comment: @mscnvrsy hmmm.... I'm confused now where MATLAB's red line in the QQPlot is coming from :P Gimme a sec... I'm checking the source code...

Comment: For me it looks more like it's an OLS fit. But unfortunately one cannot set any relevant parameters in the `qqplot()`.

Comment: @mscnvrsy It's gotta be something like that. You maybe could copy the code in `/toolbox/stats/stats/qqplot.m` (or wherever it is... use `which qqplot` to find) to ~MATLAB/myqqplot.m and then edit it so it does what you want.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I might switch to `normplot()` instead to avoid confusion. Just to clarify, the qqplot shows that the sample has fatter tails than generated by a normal, doesn't it? EDIT: I found this in the qqplot function: "A reference line passing through  the first and third quartiles is helpful for judging whether the points are linear."

Answer (score 3):

How the line is determined varies from package to package but one common way is to join the lower-quartile point $(x,y)=(-0.6745,Q_1)$ to the upper-quartile point $(0.6745,Q_3)$.

Looking at the Matlab help for qqplot, that's actually what it says Matlab does.

The sample distribution is peaked and heavy-tailed in a manner that makes its quartiles closer together than they are for a normal with the same standard deviation, which makes the slope nearer to 0.7 than to 1.