# How does plotting QQ plot on ggplot work?

Tags: regression, r, qq-plot, ggplot2

I am new to r programming and have ran into an odd situation while plotting a QQ plot for studentised residuals with ggplot2. See code and plot below:

```
> rstandard(model_iq)
          1           2           3           4           5           6           7           8           9          10          11          12          13 
 1.13429572  1.16124625  0.47049187  0.83542825 -0.18827262  0.47293724 -0.34506576 -1.29589101  1.43866080  1.02882375 -0.19085879  0.50767008  1.99950824 
         14          15          16          17          18          19          20          21          22          23          24          25          26 
-0.86482930 -0.50277823  0.72606420 -0.66445743 -0.77124490 -1.11242024 -1.30150324  1.80073085  0.52791966 -0.02534021  0.77932014 -0.72089642 -1.00615253 
         27          28          29          30          31          32          33          34          35          36          37          38 
-1.28725357  0.83347411  1.27023923  0.98982050 -0.58952946 -1.06235680 -1.05706351  0.56601524  0.36680592 -0.75715996 -1.91748085 -1.23402619

  ggplot(data_iq, aes(sample = rstandard(model_iq))) +
  stat_qq_band(alpha = 0.4) +
  stat_qq_point(shape = 21,  size = 3, fill = "blue3", colour = "grey60") +
  stat_qq_line(col = "red", linetype = "dashed")
```

### [image: 1]

What I am trying to do is simply to check if my studentised residuals have a normal distribution.

My question is this: Why is my `stat_qq_line()` not a line where x = y? Is there something I am missing here with regards to QQ plotting for studentised residuals? I noticed that my data would fit far better if I have a stat_qq_line() where x = y.

I do not believe this is a complicated question, but ChatGPT has been fairly useless in helping understand whether the `stat_qq_line()` is wrong and why. Pardon my ignorance, but I hope that someone could enlighten me as to why `stat_qq_line()` takes on the values it does and whether I can use it as is to verify normality. This is my first time plotting QQ plots and I am trying to understand how this works.

Comment: Maybe this very similar discussion can help: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/240659/qq-plot-reference-line-not-45

Comment: There are two different `stat_qq_line` functions, one in `ggplot2` and another in `qqplotr` and they do different things.  Can you specify which you are using?

Comment: @GeorgeSavva the `stat_qq_line` function i am referring to is the one in `qqplotr`. I believe its counterpart in `ggplot2` is `geom_qq_line`

Comment: @Mathemagician777 thank you so much for the link, let me read and digest what it is saying!

Comment: Trying using the base functions qqnorm() and qqline() or qqPlot() from the car package and see if they show similar output

Comment: @jack sure, I will get to that and post my findings here